# LaTeX Error: Command \widering already defined

Tags: newtxmath, mathabx

I'm not sure why I keep getting this error with the specific `newtxmath` package; all I want is to use this package alongside `newtxtext` so I can have TNR for my text and math fonts.

Is there some conflict with my imports that I'm just not seeing? I've tried going through and commenting some out with a few listed as ``required'' meaning they're vital to the project I'm working on.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% \usepackage{times}
\usepackage{pdfpages}     % Required
\usepackage{amsmath}      % Required
\usepackage{amssymb}      % Required
\usepackage{mathabx}      % Required
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{prooftrees}
% \usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{syntax}
% \usepackage{baskervald}
% \usepackage{charter}
% \usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[super]{nth} 
% \usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{simplebnf}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
% \usepackage[varvw]{newtxmath}
% \usepackage{mathptmx}
% \usepackage{txfonts}
```

Comment: Are you absolutely, positively certain that loading the `mathabx` party is *required*? If one doesn't load `mathabx`, your preamble is fine.

Comment: @Mico Yes, it's required. I use the `\dotdiv` command which is loaded by `mathabx`. I'm not sure if there's an alternative that works as well as this command does, sadly. I'll probably just have to go looking for one.

Comment: You could add `\let\widering\relax` and `\let\widebar\relax` before `\usepackage{newtxmath}`

Answer (score 3):

The `mathabx` package is never vital. And, in general, you cannot hope to mix different math symbol fonts such as `mathabx` and `newtxmath` (but also `mathpazo`).

If you just need *one* symbol from `mathabx`, import it. By the way, you don't need `amssymb` either, because the symbols it provides are already covered by `newtxmath`. Unfortunately, `prooftrees` loads it anyway, so some precedence has to be be established.

```
\documentclass{article}

% to be loaded first in order to avoid conflicts
\usepackage{prooftrees}
\usepackage{amsthm}

% fonts
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[
  %varvw,
]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{pifont}

% math or related
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{simplebnf}

% typesetting
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{framed}% <- really?
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{syntax}% <- really
\usepackage[super]{nth} 

% import \dotdiv
\DeclareRobustCommand{\dotdiv}{\mathbin{\text{\mathabxdotdiv}}}
\newcommand{\mathabxdotdiv}{\usefont{U}{mathb}{m}{n}\symbol{"01}}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> mathb5 <5.5-6.5> mathb6 <6.5-7.5> mathb7
  <7.5-8.5> mathb8 <8.5-9.5> mathb9 <9.5-11> mathb10
  <11-> mathb12 }{}
% end import

% fix \widering (remove \smash and add \vss)
\renewcommand{\widering}[1]{%
  \overset{%
    \vbox to .2ex{%
      \hbox{$\mathring{}$}%
      \vss
    }
  }{\overgroup{#1}}}
% end fix

\begin{document}

\[
\widering{abc}\dotdiv x
\]

\end{document}
```

I reorganized package loading to avoid conflicts and duplications. Next I show how to import the single symbol `\dotdiv`.

A fix to the badly written definition of `\widering` is also provided (the one in `newtxmath` produces four overfull `\vbox` warning at each call.

[image]

I commented out `framed` because you're already loading `tcolorbox` that offers much more. About `syntax`: it's a very old an long unmaintained package that can create conflicts. You already have `prooftrees` and `simplebnf`: do you also really need `syntax`?